Python Script to Parse and Format Address Data Using Pandas and usaddress
I'm working on a Python script to parse and format address data using Pandas and the usaddress library. I have a DataFrame with two columns: address_main and address_cnr. Each row contains an address in the address_main column and a corner address in the address_cnr column.
Here's a sample input DataFrame:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'address_main': ['585 - 595 salisbury highway', '91 queen street', 'arndale shopping centre', 'bay street', 'capalaba park shopping centre'],
    'address_cnr': ['cnr. greenfields drive', 'cnr albert & elizabeth streets', 'cnr hanson & torrens rd', 'cnr park street', 'cnr redland bay & mt cotton road']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

I want to parse these addresses using the usaddress library and format the parsed components into separate columns in the DataFrame. Here's the desired output format:
address_main,address_cnr,street_number,street_name1,street_type1,street_name2,street_type2,street_name3,street_type3
585 - 595 salisbury highway,cnr. greenfields drive,585 - 595,salisbury,highway,greenfields,drive,,
91 queen street,cnr albert & elizabeth streets,91,queen,street,albert,street,elizabeth,street
arndale shopping centre,cnr hanson & torrens rd,,hanson,rd,torrens,rd,,
bay street,cnr park street,.bay,street,park,street,,
capalaba park shopping centre,cnr redland bay & mt cotton road,,redland,bay,mt cotton,road,,

I've written a script to achieve this, but I'm having trouble getting the desired output format. Can someone please help me modify my script or suggest a better approach to achieve the desired output?
Here's the script I have so far:
import pandas as pd
import usaddress

# Sample data
data = {
    'address_main': ['585 - 595 salisbury highway', '91 queen street', 'arndale shopping centre', 'bay street', 'capalaba park shopping centre'],
    'address_cnr': ['cnr. greenfields drive', 'cnr albert & elizabeth streets', 'cnr hanson & torrens rd', 'cnr park street', 'cnr redland bay & mt cotton road']
}

# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def parse_address(address):
    try:
        # Use usaddress to tag the address
        parsed_address, address_type = usaddress.tag(address)
        return parsed_address
    except usaddress.RepeatedLabelError as e:
        print(f"Error parsing address '{address}': {e}")
        return {}

def extract_address_components(parsed_address, prefix='street'):
    components = {
        f'{prefix}_number': parsed_address.get('AddressNumber', ''),
        f'{prefix}_name1': parsed_address.get('StreetName', ''),
        f'{prefix}_type1': parsed_address.get('StreetNamePostType', ''),
        f'{prefix}_name2': '',
        f'{prefix}_type2': '',
        f'{prefix}_name3': '',
        f'{prefix}_type3': ''
    }

    # Handle second street name and type if present
    if 'SecondStreetName' in parsed_address:
        components[f'{prefix}_name2'] = parsed_address['SecondStreetName']
    if 'SecondStreetPostType' in parsed_address:
        components[f'{prefix}_type2'] = parsed_address['SecondStreetPostType']

    return components

# Initialize new columns in the DataFrame
df['street_number'] = ''
df['street_name1'] = ''
df['street_type1'] = ''
df['street_name2'] = ''
df['street_type2'] = ''
df['street_name3'] = ''
df['street_type3'] = ''

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # Parse the main address
    parsed_main = parse_address(row['address_main'])
    main_components = extract_address_components(parsed_main, 'street')
    
    # Check if AddressNumber, StreetName, StreetType are present in the main address
    if main_components['street_number']:
        df.at[index, 'street_number'] = main_components['street_number']
    if main_components['street_name1']:
        df.at[index, 'street_name1'] = main_components['street_name1']
    if main_components['street_type1']:
        df.at[index, 'street_type1'] = main_components['street_type1']
    
    # Parse the corner address for additional street names and types
    parsed_cnr = parse_address(row['address_cnr'])
    cnr_components = extract_address_components(parsed_cnr, 'street')
    
    if cnr_components['street_name1']:
        df.at[index, 'street_name2'] = cnr_components['street_name1']
    if cnr_components['street_type1']:
        df.at[index, 'street_type2'] = cnr_components['street_type1']
    
    if cnr_components['street_name2']:
        df.at[index, 'street_name3'] = cnr_components['street_name2']
    if cnr_components['street_type2']:
        df.at[index, 'street_type3'] = cnr_components['street_type2']

df.head()

current code producing this output:
address_main,address_cnr,street_number,street_name1,street_type1,street_name2,street_type2,street_name3,street_type3
585 - 595 salisbury highway,cnr. greenfields drive,585-595,salisbury,highway,greenfields,drive,,
91 queen street,cnr albert & elizabeth streets,91,queen,street,albert,,elizabeth,streets
arndale shopping centre,cnr hanson & torrens rd,,,,hanson,,torrens,rd
bay street,cnr park street,,bay,street,park,street,,
capalaba park shopping centre,cnr redland bay & mt cotton road,,,,mt cotton,road,,


The usaddress library which is specifically designed for parsing US addresses. If your data contains non-US addresses, the parsing might not be accurate.
import pandas as pd
import usaddress

data = {
    'address_main': ['585 - 595 salisbury highway', '91 queen street', 'arndale shopping centre', 'bay street', 'capalaba park shopping centre'],
    'address_cnr': ['cnr. greenfields drive', 'cnr albert & elizabeth streets', 'cnr hanson & torrens rd', 'cnr park street', 'cnr redland bay & mt cotton road']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def parse_and_extract(address, prefix='street'):
    try:
        parsed_address, _ = usaddress.tag(address)
    except usaddress.RepeatedLabelError:
        parsed_address = {}
    
    components = {f'{prefix}_{key}': parsed_address.get(key, '') for key in ['AddressNumber', 'StreetName', 'StreetNamePostType', 'SecondStreetName', 'SecondStreetNamePostType']}
    components[f'{prefix}_name3'] = parsed_address.get('ThirdStreetName', '')
    components[f'{prefix}_type3'] = parsed_address.get('ThirdStreetNamePostType', '')
    
    return components

df = df.join(df['address_main'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(parse_and_extract(x.replace(' - ', '-'), 'street'))))
df = df.join(df['address_cnr'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(parse_and_extract(x, 'street'))))

print(df.head())

parse_address and extract_address_components functions to each address in the DataFrame using the apply function. It then joins the resulting DataFrame to the original DataFrame. This should give you the desired output format.

Note this script assumes that the address_main and address_cnr
columns do not contain any null values.


I appologize I put the old testing code where I was testing ThirdStreetPostType key in usaddress but there is no key named ThirdStreetPostType or ThirdStreetName. I have updated the code. Sorry about that again.

actually address_cnr contains some null values so how can I overcome this if I have to handle null values to join dataframes?

Fill NA/NaN values with an empty string
df['address_cnr'] = df['address_cnr'].fillna('')
Now apply the parse_and_extract function
df = df.join(df['address_cnr'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(parse_and_extract(x, 'street'))))

I am getting this error on joining the dataframes: ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['street_number', 'street_name1', 'street_type1', 'street_name2',        'street_type2', 'street_name3', 'street_type3'],       dtype='object')
